# R Printing specific columns

Tags: r, csv, multiple-columns, sink

I have this file test.csv. I have used -

```
test <- read.csv ("test.csv", check.names=FALSE)
```

To get it into R. I have used check.names as the column headers contains brackets and if I dont use it, they turn into periods which I have issues with when coding.

I have then done this-

```
sink(file='interest.txt')
print((test["test$log(I)">=1 & test$number >= 6 , "Name"]),)
```

My aim is to create a sink file so the print output is put into there. I wanted to print the value in the name column if the values for 2 columns (log(I) and number) equal a certain value.

```
log(I) Number Name
1.00     6    LAMP1
3.50     6    MND1 
1.20     2    GGD3
0.98     7    KLP1
```

So in this example, the code would output just LAMP1 and MND1 to the sink file I created.

My issue is that I don't think R is recognising that log(I) is the header title as it seems to give me the same result with or without this part included.
If I dont use

```
check.names=FALSE
```

Then the column is turned to log.I. instead. How can I get around this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps using backticks around the variable name will help, e.g.: test$\`log(I)\`

Comment: Or perhaps test["log(I)"]

Comment: Since it is in a file to start with and you want to output a file after some selection and formatting, this sounds like a perfect job for `awk`. Something like `awk -F , '( /log/ || $1 == 1 || $2 == 6 )  { print $1 "\t" "$2" "\t" $3 }' test.csv > interest.txt`

Comment: @vaettchen I am doing this on R though, will that work?

Comment: No, that would be outside `R`. Just an idea, if you are not comfortable, no need to spend time.

Comment: @vaettchen ah okay thanks but ideally I need to keep it within R for the mean time